# Is there some way to do `bufdo` in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, vim-emulation

I am very used to using `bufdo` from vim to perform an action across all buffers.  I can do things like

```
:bufdo %s/\( *\), top=/\1, blockTop=/
```

to do a search an replace over multiple buffers or

```
:bufdo w | !pdflatex %
```

To compile each buffer as a Latex file.

I'm really new to spacemacs and I'd like to be able to do this sort of thing where I just run my vim command over every buffer.  Is there some way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not all buffers in Emacs are visiting files, so you would basically never want to do something like a search and replace across "all buffers".

For ad-hoc use I would use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` to mark the target buffers (marking by major mode is probably a useful way to go), and then one of the following:

- <kbd>r</kbd> (`ibuffer-do-replace-regexp`)
- <kbd>Q</kbd> (`ibuffer-do-query-replace`)
- <kbd>I</kbd> (`ibuffer-do-query-replace-regexp`)
- <kbd>!</kbd> (`ibuffer-do-shell-command-file`) runs a shell command on the buffer's file.

There are many other things you can do.  See the "Mark" and "Operate" menus in the `ibuffer` buffer, and use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> in that buffer to learn more.

Comment: Interesting.  This works for replacement which is nice, but it won't let me do my other example, where I compile as Latex.

Comment: `!` runs a shell command on the buffer's file.  Again: "See the "Mark" and "Operate" menus" (or use `C-h m`).  There are lots of things you can do.

Comment: I recommend re-binding `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer` to replace the default (but less-capable) `list-buffers` command.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the shell command example.